# Setting up CI with [Jenkins, TeamCity, etc] - which source code control?

Tags: version-control, svn, continuous-integration, dvcs, jenkins

I am bound and determined to setup CI at work. I have played with Jenkins, and will download TeamCity when I get home (damn you work enforced download filters!) I have no IT support, and only so much spare time. My main question:

Can Jenkins or TeamCity integrate with git or mercurial repositories that exist only on a shared drive rather than a true server (via http, https, ssh, etc)?

I would like to use a DVCS with my CI setup, but would also be ok with settling on SVN because it is familiar, and already setup (but no projects to migrate if I decide on a DVCS). I am familiar with the benefits of DVCS and I don't think they will come into play very often in my current environment.

My CI will live on a plain Windows XP box on the network. Given the above, will it be fairly easy to integrate either Jenkins or TeamCity with git/mercurial, or should I just stick with SVN as it is more or less ready to go?

Comment: Jenkins works fine with git.  Note that a complete repository is checked out per job.

Comment: We use Jenkins with SVN and Git simultaneously (well, one VCS per job of course) and it works just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modern CI server solutions do not limit you to a single (D)VCS.

With Jenkins and  Teamcity you are free to choose Git or SVN (or Mercurial, or TFS, or anything else). Both server support file:// urls, so you'll be able to use shared drive. No big difference here.

If you don't want to spend lots of time configuring and supporting your server, I'd choose TeamCity. This thing "just works" and have a pretty Windows installer that will bring up TeamCity server in no time.

Comment: +1 for TeamCity just working.  It is definitely a solid CI tool.

Comment: TeamCity needs to run a client thread to check for changes for each type of repo, so it might help to make up your mind in choosing SVN or Git or Mercurial, although you can use them all.